# Android Amplify Auth Signout Timing Out

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've been working on learning Amplify Framework for Android in Kotlin. Previously, with help from the SO community, I was able to set up Authentication via the Cognito Hosted UI. I could sign in and out, and query a DynamoDB user table, cool.

I was using a second Activity `AuthActivity` with a viewmodel to handle login/logout. However, I want to migrate to a 1 Activity n Fragments system. The viewmodel had the Amplify auth calls defined (bad I know), so I whipped up a `LoginFragment` that utilizes the same viewmodel. Then, I added the `HostedUIRedirectActivity` to `AndroidManifest`to upgrade from the [Response Handler described in the docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin_web_ui/q/platform/android#add-response-handler). Not sure why I didn't do that originally, but it is the root of my problem.

**The Problem**

After updating `AndroidManifest`, the sign in/out flows using the Cognito Hosted UI are producing errors and otherwise strange behavior. `Amplify.Auth.signOut()` calls respond with a timeout error, and I can set a breakpoint in the `onError` callback to prove it. `Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI()` seemingly works by bringing me to the Hosted UI, and then back to the `LoginFragment`, but is not hitting any of the code in the `onSuccess` callback. Also, once the user is logged in and the Login button is clicked again, the Hosted UI flashes for a second, but I expect it to ask to sign in as the same user or another user.

**What I've Done**

- Moved the auth code straight into the `LoginFragment` to make it easy to post here, got the same behavior.
- Noticed that in the Hosted UI Activity in `AndroidManifest` had a line `<data android:scheme="myapp" />` so I changed that value to the actual name of the app. The problem persists.
- Noticed in the docs that Amplify versions 1.17.7 and below "have known issues with sign-out after signing in via web UI". This sounded likely to be my issue, so I did a `npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli` to update just in case. I'm on version 5.0. Problem persists.

I will post my code below. I can clarify anything or post more if necessary. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**My Code**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewmodel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.authViewModel = viewmodel
        val view = binding.root
        binding.btnSignIn.setOnClickListener { btnLoginOnClick(view) }
        binding.btnSignout.setOnClickListener { btnLogoutOnClick(view) }
        return view
    }

    fun signInWithWebUI(a: Activity) {
        Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(a,
            { Log.i(tag, "loginSuccess") },
            { Log.e(tag, "loginError", it) } )
    }

    fun btnLoginOnClick(view: View) { signInWithWebUI(activity as MainActivity) }

    fun signOut() {
        Amplify.Auth.signOut(
            { Log.i(tag, "logoutSuccess") },
            { Log.e(tag, "logoutError", it) } )
    }

    fun btnLogoutOnClick(view: View) { signOut() }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I solved my problem.

The `AndroidManifest` had an Activity called `CustomTabsRedirectActivity` that I do not recall placing there. Maybe Amplify did that automatically. Anyway, I removed that Activity block and tested again. The sign in callbacks are now hit, and sign out succeeds in a flash.

The `AndroidManifest` stuff goes over my head a fair amount, so if what I did was wrong I'd love to hear an explanation or suggestions. Otherwise I'm going to mark this as accepted when I'm allowed.

Hope this maybe helps someone else in my position.